# Performing pixel- and channelwise division in PhotoShop

Tags: photoshop, calculations, negative-film, negative-scanner

Every negative has certain base color, i.e. the color of unexposed areas.  I want to know how to fraction this number out of my scans.

In pure math, this is nothing particularly strange, I assume that all colors are coded in RGB values between 0 and 1 and that in my scan result the base color `B` is multiplied with the color information `C` of the photograph.  So to retrieve the original value `C` all I have to do is a pixel- and channelwise division by `B`.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to easily achieve this in PhotoShop.  Is there any blending mode acting as division on the RGB values?  Or any other operation doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blending-modes.html

> Divide
>
> Looks at the color information in each channel and divides the blend color from the base color.

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/channel-calculations.html

> Channel Calculations
>
> The calculation commands perform mathematical operations on the corresponding pixels of two channels (the pixels with identical locations in the image) and then combine the results in a single channel. Two concepts are fundamental to understanding how the calculation commands work:
>
> Each pixel in a channel has a brightness value. The Calculations and Apply Image commands manipulate these values to produce the resulting composite pixels.
>
> These commands overlay the pixels in two or more channels. Thus, the images used for calculations must have the same pixel dimensions.